# How to fix Flutter error: "Type 'Item' not found."

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

This code has been working for several weeks, but suddenly brought up errors after an AndroidStudio update:

```
    class _GameState extends State<Game> {
  List<Item> its = [
    Item('fins','images/idea-fins.png'),
    Item('sonar','images/idea-sonar.png'),
    Item('suction','images/idea-suction.png'),
    Item('tires','images/idea-tire.png'),
    Item('velcro','images/idea-velcro.png'),
    Item('propeller','images/idea-propeller.png')
  ];
```

The error I get is:

```
    Error: Type 'Item' not found.
  List<Item> its = [
```

Does "Item" now have to be defined, somehow, or has some more fundamental change been made?

Comment: didnt u import the Item model ? in the file?

Comment: Import your item file

Comment: Like this.
```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as Items;
```
???

Comment: This says that using "List" in this form is depreciated:
[link](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.1/dart-core/List/List.html)
This has similar examples, but require adding a "class" that I haven't been able to get to work:
[link](https://medium.com/geekculture/the-best-list-handling-methods-in-flutter-and-dart-c45b1116bb82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this near the beginning and now it works:

```
class Item {
  String name="";
  bool dropped=false;
  String pic="";

  Item(String a, String b)
  {
    name =a;
    pic =b;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st case :
You havent import the package please import the package

example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

2nd Case : You have imported it already but still showing this . then do like this :

example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as app; **//in your case as Items for your package url**
```

then do like this:

```
   class _GameState extends State<Game> {
  List<Items.Item> its = [
    Items .Item('fins','images/idea-fins.png'),
    Items.Item('sonar','images/idea-sonar.png'),
   Items.Item('suction','images/idea-suction.png'),
   Items.Item('tires','images/idea-tire.png'),
    Items.Item('velcro','images/idea-velcro.png'),
    Items.Item('propeller','images/idea-propeller.png')
  ];
```

---

It cause because of same package name declared

Comment: When I
```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as Items;
```
and do this:
```
        class _GameState extends State<Game> {
  List<Items.Item> its = [
    Items.Item('fins','images/idea-fins.png'),
    Items.Item('sonar','images/idea-sonar.png'),
    Items.Item('suction','images/idea-suction.png'),
    Items.Item('tires','images/idea-tire.png'),
    Items.Item('velcro','images/idea-velcro.png'),
    Items.Item('propeller','images/idea-propeller.png')
  ];
```

Comment: I get:
```
Unhandled exception:
Crash when compiling null,
at character offset null:
Null check operator used on a null value
#0      InferableTypeBuilderMixin.type (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/type_builder.dart:392:29)
#1      InferableTypeBuilder.inferType (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/omitted_type_builder.dart:155:12)
```